# Search all tables in Oracle DB

Tags: search, full-text-search, oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10g at the moment.  I want to search through all the tables for a certain word or phrase.

How would I go about searching all the tables for the word of phrase?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Oracle Text](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/text/x/10g_tech_overview.html)(10g edition).